# How to avoid a race condition when keyup event is sent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a function `matcher` which is called every time a keyup event is sent.

This function belongs to a module which look like this (1).
what if another call is done before the fetching is completed?
How can I solve this problem in this module (1)?

---

(1)

```
(function ($, UserCollection) {

    var userCollection;

    var matcher = function (request, response) {
        if (!userCollection) {
            userCollection = new UserCollection();
            userCollection.fetch();
        } else {
            isMatched(request, response);
        }
    };

    return matcher;
}(jquery, UserCollection));
```

Comment: Note your `matcher` function is (or at least appears to be) global. Can you explain a little more (edit the question if necessary) about what you want and what's happening?

Comment: u can done this thing with javascript progress bar http://www.knowledgebase.vunet.us/web/progressbar.html

Comment: @Utkanos I fixed the code. I would like to avoid the `matcher` function to be called when the `userCollection.fetch` is running and not completed.

Comment: @Lorraine Bernard I would suggest you to toggle the event listener for keyup event during fetch and after fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a different, probably overkill, approach and use the [jqXHR object returned by `collection.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).

```
var Matcher=(function($,UserCollection) {

    var xhr=null, userCollection=null;

    // matching against a defined ID for testing purpose
    function isMatched(id) {
        return userCollection.get(id);
    }

    // the request would be an ID in my example,
    // and the callback is the function invoked when the collection is fetched
    function matcher(request, callback) {
        if (!xhr) {
            userCollection = new UserCollection();

            // fetch returns a handy xhr object used for the deferred
            xhr=userCollection.fetch(); 
        }

        xhr.then(function() {
            callback(isMatched(request));
        });
    }       

    return matcher;

})(jQuery, UserCollection);
```

If the xhr is already resolved, the callback is immediately invoked, if not, it will be when the request completes : see [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more info.

And you would use it as

```
Matcher(1,console.log);
Matcher(2,console.log);
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EWSAV/1/

Comment: thanks for your response. it seems the best one. just one question what's about `xhr.then`? because I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined `

Comment: @LorraineBernard If you look at http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch, it should be the object used by jQuery to represent the Ajax request. I tested it on jQuery 1.7.2 and Backbone 0.9.2

Comment: @nikoshr @LorraineBernard maybe did you want to make something like this `$.when(xhr).then(function() {... })`?

Comment: @AntoJs that's equivalent, xhr is already a deferred http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: @LorraineBernard I added a Fiddle to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

As long as you run synchronous actions this should be no problem, because the events get executed in a timely manner.

However, you could add a second variable which indicates if a matching is in progress.

Something like this:

```
(function ($, UserCollection) {

    var userCollection;
    var inProgress = false;

    var matcher = function (request, response) {
        if (!inProgress){
           if (!userCollection) {
               inProgress = true;
               userCollection = new UserCollection();
               userCollection.fetch();
           } else {
               isMatched(request, response);
           }
           // inProgress = false; - after your asynchonous code is executed
        }
    };

    return matcher;
}(jquery, UserCollection));
```

This code probably won't work, but I think you got the idea.

This approach however might require your asynchronous script to be in the same scope to have access to `inProgress`. The better option might be to work with callbacks on the fetch:

```
userCollection.fetch({ success:function(){inProgress=false} });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch), `fetch()` accepts a callback function to be called after a successful "fetch". So you can have a global variable indicating the state of the current "fetch". This is the basic idea, I think you can work your way from here

```
fetching = false;
//Event fired ->
if (!fetching ){
fetching = true;
..fetch({success: function(){fetching = false;}});
}
```